# Porque minha tag "th" tem espaço entre as colunas depois que aplico background?

Tags: html5, css3

Boa tarde! Então galera, quando estou aplicando background no meu th as colunas ficam separadas, como podem ver na imagem. Podem me ajudar a entender o porque, obrigado!

[image: resultado da tabela]

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lista de pedidos</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">        
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>-</th>
                    <th>Mercado</th>
                    <th>Pedido</th>
                    <th>Valor</th>
                    <th>Data</th>
                    <th>Situação</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Logo</td>
                    <td>Loja1</td>
                    <td>200201197</td>
                    <td>R$10000</td>
                    <td>21-12-2019</td>
                    <td>Pedido entregue</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.css

```
th {
    background: #C0C0C0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É porque a `<table>` por padrão tem a propriedade `cellspacing` definida em 1. Esse 1 é o espaço... defina para 0 que resolverá.

```
<table cellspacing="0">
...
</table>
```

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado Bruno!